# apt-get upgrade to exclude some updates

Tags: apt

I want to exclude some package(s) when choosing to `apt-get upgrade`.  I'm thinking an edit to source.list probably?  For example, maybe a package that updates often with minor point releases, or minor issues to attend to manually first.  I'm thinking of *percona* specifically.

```
libmysqlclient16 libmysqlclient18 percona-server-client 
percona-server-client-5.5 percona-server-common-5.5 percona-server-server 
percona-server-server-5.5
```

I still want to run `apt-get upgrade` and have it update everything it finds normally, except what I've asked to be held back or **libmysql*** and **percona*** if possible.

Then I'm not sure yet how I'll upgrade these others manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pinning Packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) or Holding.

This should give a good overview of this.  I have had to use it on a server to hold back updates and upgrades for MySQL until a content management system was ready.

Comment: great, I think you led me in the right direction!  Found this with some good examples of holding: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=55178#p319498

Comment: Also, don't forget to reference the man for apt.  It actually talks about pinning in there.  If you need details let me know. I still have my old pinning that I used for php related things for Karmic.